# XMPPFramework - When does 'didRecieveIQ' gets called?

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework

I implemented the following method in AppDelegate.m.

```
- (BOOL)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveIQ:(XMPPIQ *)iq
```

Can somebody tell me in which case(s) does this method gets called and what is the purpose of this method?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for getting roster list

```
-(void)fetchRosterListWithUserId:(NSString *)userId // yourID
    {
        NSXMLElement *query = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"query" xmlns:@"jabber:iq:roster"];
        XMPPIQ *iq = [XMPPIQ iq];
        [iq addAttributeWithName:@"id" stringValue:FETCH_ROSTER_DISCO_ID];
        [iq addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:userId];
        [iq addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"get"];
        [iq addChild:query];
        [_xmppStream sendElement:iq];
    }
```

You can get the response back in

```
- (BOOL)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveIQ:(XMPPIQ *)iq`
```

Comment: Thank you suhail. Actually I am new to xmppframework implementation. Thats why i need some help. Thaks a lot

Comment: You are free to ask.I worked on that before 6 month for creating a xmpp library, now i forgot something.

Comment: instead of FETCH_ROSTER_DISCO_ID what value i have to replace?

Comment: Any value u can replace , its just for identification of response, but it should be unique

Comment: Is there any complete book or tutorial available. I am facing many kind of problem.

Comment: http://oriolrius.cat/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/Oreilly.XMPP.The.Definitive.Guide.May.2009.pdf

Comment: Hi suhail. Thanks for book. I had read 2nd chapter of it. there are beautiful explanation regarding xmpp are there. Now, how can i parse that IQ. I mean how to get all jid string from server response..

Comment: Ask another question with response,here ur question and our discussions are diffrent

Answer (score 1):

This will getting called as a response of any XMPP query(XMPPIQ) like

```
  NSXMLElement *query = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"query" xmlns:SERVER_DISCO_ITEMS];
    XMPPIQ *iq = [XMPPIQ iq];
    [iq addAttributeWithName:@"id" stringValue:FETCH_SERVER_DISCO_ID];
    [iq addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:serverName];
    [iq addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"get"];
    [iq addChild:query];
    [_xmppStream sendElement:iq];
```

As a response of this you can get a call back with response to

```
- (BOOL)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveIQ:(XMPPIQ *)iq
```

Comment: Thaks for replay. In my appdelegate.m file,where I have to place this code? can You Please Help....

Comment: its xmppsream delegate method.where you create xmppStream object and setDelegate ,in same class you place this method

Comment: I am talking about NSXMLElement *query object.

Comment: Where u want to query to something, u create a query like this and send to server

Comment: actually I want my buddy list when my application launch. How can I do that any sample code.

Answer (score -1):

It will be called when, for example, your friend will have deleted your account from his friends list.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @serenesat Looks like an answer to me.